Opensearch query to fetch documents if match count on a multivalue field is greater than 1
I have an index of customers that has an address field with a comma separated string containing the customer's addresses.
e.g.
id:c1, addressList:a1,a2,a3
id:c2, addressList:a4,a5,a6
id:c3, addressList:a1,a7
id:c4, addressList:a2,a5
id:c5, addressList:a8

Not relevant, but the normalized address string would be something like
1234_water_dr_suite_10_montgomery_ny_23134

What I'm trying to find is all the customers that share an address.  So, in the above example, I should get back
a1 - c1,c3
a2 - c1,c4
a5 - c2,c4 

At the moment, I'm using a brute force approach which I'm sure can be improved.
I first get all the addresses using the following query and tokenize them to get a set of all addresses.  In this case (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8)
{
    "size": 10000,
    "_source": false,
    "fields": ["addressList"],
    "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "addressList"
        }
    }
}

I don't there's much I can do about that part and it's fairly fast anyway.
The problem I have is to do the next bit.  Right now, I'm looping through all the addresses I got and making a call for each address
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "addressList": "<currAddress>"
        }
    } 
}

What I'd like is a way to pass in the list of addresses I get back and get back only those customers whose document count exceeds 1.  Which is a1, a2 and a5 in the above example.
Since it's a comma separated list, it's a text field. I can't make it a term field and hence can't use aggregations to use a min_doc_count
Is there a better approach I can take?

Tldr;
If you were okay to modify your mapping you could perform the whole thing in a single query.
Demo
PUT _ingest/pipeline/split_addresses
{
  "processors": [
      {
        "split": {
          "field": "addresses",
          "separator": ",",
          "target_field": "addressesList"
        }
      }
    ]
}



POST 79232196/_bulk?pipeline=split_addresses&refresh=true
{"index":{}}
{"customer": "c1", "addresses": "a1,a2,a3"}
{"index":{}}
{"customer": "c2", "addresses": "a4,a5,a6"}
{"index":{}}
{"customer": "c3", "addresses": "a1,a7"}
{"index":{}}
{"customer": "c4", "addresses": "a2,a5"}
{"index":{}}
{"customer": "c5", "addresses": "a8"}



GET 79232196/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "streets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "addressesList.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "clients": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "customer.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Should give you the following results:
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 5,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "streets": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "a1",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "clients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "c1",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "c3",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "a2",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "clients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "c1",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "c4",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "a5",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "clients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "c2",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "c4",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "a3",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "clients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "c1",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "a4",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "clients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "c2",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "a6",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "clients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "c2",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "a7",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "clients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "c3",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "a8",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "clients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "c5",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

